# Accessing Element in Style ControlTemplate using its Name, from a Style BasedOn it

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a Style say ButtonStyle for a Button, that has VisualStates, Properties and Triggers inside it. I have another style BasedOn ButtonStyle. I need to access an element named "OnhoverGrid" inside the BasedOn style, to change its properties. The ControlTemplate in ButtonStyle contains many elements and setters on them. I cannot set a new Template with code copied from the existing ControlTemplate for the BasedOn style. Is there a way I can access the element OnhoverGrid from inside my BasedOn style triggers? Here is a sample snippet of the Styles.

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid x:Name="OnhoverGrid" Opacity="0" Background="Blue">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="OnhoverGrid" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="OnhoverGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red" /><!-- Unable to access on OnhoverGrid-->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: you can try to bind the OnhoverGrid background to some dynamic resource(like visual brash) and then you can manage  that resource by changing  its content when trigger is happend.